# Chef LWRP referencing relative resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to create a *LWRP* to extend a supermarket cookbook '*webpshere*'.

In my resource file, I am trying to extend this class with a base class found in parent cook book.

In the code below, *'WebsphereBase'* is defined in the parent library 'websphere_base'. Can I get help on how to reference it? 
Thanks

```
    #require 'websphere_base'
    module PIWebsphereCookBook
    class WebsphereJbdc < WebsphereBase
    require_relative 'helper'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source of the cookbook](https://github.com/Sainsburys/chef-websphere/blob/master/libraries/websphere_base.rb), you can see that the `WebsphereBase` class is defined inside the `WebsphereCookbook` module.

To reference this class from outside this module, you have to name the nesting so that Ruby is able to find the class you are referring to. With youur example, this can look similar to:

```
module PIWebsphereCookBook
  class WebsphereJbdc < WebsphereCookbook::WebsphereBase
    require_relative 'helper'
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to require things coming from upstream cookbooks, nor can you (except for my weirdo cookbooks). All libs for cookbooks you depend on will be loaded by the time your library files run.

Comment: sorry I didn't get your suggestion. Here I am trying to extend the behavior (adding 'jdbc' which is not handled) hence was extending the WebsphereBase class to reuse functions. In another case - I was able to access the libraries (guess it is same as your suggestion) and I am just using it as shown below. 
module ArtifactClientCookbook
  module Helper
    require 'artifactory'
    include Artifactory::Resource